# How do you solve a loom scheduling algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming

**Domain:**

A carpet factory want's to optimize their planning system. For now, they just plan the carpets manually, but they want this automated.

**How is a carpet made?:**

Every carpet has 3 kinds of thread:

- Vertically
- Horizontally(yarn)
- (Pile thread)

[image: Horizontal and vertical threads]

the color for the vertical thread is given, the color for the horizontal thread is given too.

Let's leave the third one for what it is because we don't need it for the problem.

You also have different looms, you can compare a loom with a 2D rectangle where the carpets are made on. Every loom has a quality and a group colors it can weave.

*For example, Loom 31 can weave quality BTU and the colors: blue, brown, yellow and purple.*

All looms have a width of 4 meters, except 1 that is 5 meters. The length of a loom is also known, let's call it **loomLength**.

A loom can be divided into sub lanes,

*for example:
Loom 31 which is 4 meters is divided into:*

1. *a lane of **120cm***
2. *a lane of **210cm***
3. *a lane of **70cm***

The number of lanes doesn't matter as long as the carpets fit on the sub lanes.

[image: The loom and sublanes]

The thread that's weaving horizontally is the **yarn**, the yarn has his own color and can't overlap a carpet with another **yarn** color. See example below:
[image: yarn colors are overlapping]

**Known variables:**

- Lw = width of loom
- Ll = Length of loom
- Lci = {Lc1,Lc2,Lc3,Lc4,...} matrix of colors that the loom can weave
- Ci = {C1,C2,C3,C4,C5,...} matrix of carpets
- Ciw = Carpet width
- Cil = Carpet length
- Ciy = Carpet yarncolor (Horizontal)
- Cim = Carpet maincolor (Vertical)

**GOAL:**

**minimize the area of lost space**

**My own research:**

I did some research concerning my problem and I saw it looked like a stock cutting problem, but I don't know how to solve mine.

I found a c# library [Microsoft Foundation Solver](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff524503(v=vs.93).aspx) that can solve stock cutting problems but I'm not sure how to apply it to my example.

***My question***
How can I solve a cutting stock problem like this with a bunch of constraints within a normal time period?

Comment: I'm afraid this is far too broad for Stack Overflow.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve] with your progress so far.

Comment: aww, have been looking for a solution for quite some time now

Comment: to be fair as someone who weaves you wouldnt use the same weft for each lane without an issue anyway

Comment: Maybe you could abstract a few subtasks, which are easier to solve and, most important, to understand; like for instance "I want to place some different colored Rectangles on a big rectangle, so that all possible lines in horizontal direction cross only rectangles with the same color or empty space...". Devide and conquer ;)